# C++ DLL: Inheritance and usage of a class defined in a static library

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, static-linking, build-tools

I'm trying to build a DLL, which implements a class that inherent from a class inside a precompiled static library.

The both projects have a shared header file where the first class is declared (*GroovyClass.h*):

```c
class GroovyClass
{
public:
    GroovyClass();
    virtual ~GroovyClass();
}
```

In the static lib this class is defined and implemented (*GroovyClass.cpp*) and compiled (let's call the result *GroovyClass.lib*).

In the shared library/DLL this class is then inherited like this:

```c
#include "GroovyClass.h"

class MassiveFail : GroovyClass
{
public:
    MassiveFail();
    virtual ~MassiveFail();
}
```

This compiles, but at the linking stage I get errors regarding **unresolved symbols** for the GroovyClass constructor and destructor. I link with *GroovyClass.lib* as usual, so I don't understand why it can't find the symbols.

Do I need to declare GroovyClass in some special way before being able to use/inherit it in my DLL project?

Comment: Try to use public inheritance. class MassiveFail : public GroovyClass

Comment: @manuell Just tried, still same *unresolved symbol* errors. 'unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl GroovyClass::GroovyClass....'

Comment: Post the *full* error message (including the mangled names) and run `dumpbin /SYMBOLS xxx.lib` to see the symbols defined in the lib.

Comment: @andsve I can reproduce yoyr problem if I "forgot" to implement the CTOR and/or DTOR in the lib. Have you double checked that GroovyClass.cpp is indeed included/compiled in your static lib project?

Comment: @MartinBa @manuell Part of `/SYMBOLS` output regarding GroovyClass [here](http://codepad.org/lhcz2aWs). And error messages when compiling the DLL [here](http://codepad.org/sQxgdmYK).

Comment: @MartinBa @manuell I found the problem, and it was my own fault all along. The build system I was using ([bam](http://matricks.github.io/bam/)) used a different "input table" when building `.lib` and `.dll`. So for future users of `bam` and search optimization; **when building a DLL, use `settings.dll` instead of `settings.link`**.

Comment: @andsve - you should add this your comment as a separate answer to this question. (Because, after all, it answers the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code and implementation was correct from the start!

**The actual problem and solution:**
The build system I was using ([bam](http://matricks.github.io/bam/)) used different "input tables" when building static libraries versus shared libraries.

So for future users of **bam**; use the table `settings.dll` instead of `settings.link` if you are building and linking a DLL.

Answer (score 0):

Can you open a Visual Studio command prompt and run DumpBin and/or Lib to see what is in GroovyClass.lib?  Make sure e.g. GroovyClass::GroovyClass is in there.

Comment: Hm, strange, there are no symbols exported when I run dumpbin /EXPORTS on the GroovyClass.lib.

Comment: @andsve - A lib doesn't need to export symbols to be usable. A lib is more or less a collection of `obj` files.

Comment: run dumpbin with the /SYMBOLS option